# Using sessions with express and websockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, session-cookies

I'm using Node, express and websockets in my app. When the user logs in their username is set in their cookie but when they reload the page it is reset to the empty string. How do I get the session to work even when they reload the page?

```
var Users = require(__dirname + '/db/databaseModel.js');

//server using express beginning of project
var express     = require('express');
var app         = express(); //create express object
var expressWs   = require('express-ws')(app); //create express websocket extension
var session     = require('express-session'); //used for user sessions
var password    = require('password-hash-and-salt'); //used for hashing password
var SQLiteStore = require('connect-sqlite3')(session);

app.use(session({ 
    key: 'express.sid',
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: true, 
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { 
        maxAge: 60000,
        username: "",
        store: new SQLiteStore
    }
}));

var gameStarted = false;
var clients = {};
var User = Users();
User.init();

app.ws('/auth', function(ws, req) { //route for checking user login
    //check for valid login
    ws.on('message', function(msg){
        console.log(msg);
        msg = JSON.parse(msg);

        if (msg.cmd === 'login'){
            User.verifyUser(msg.username, msg.password, ws, req);
        }
    });

    console.log('Login Good.');
});

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public')); //route to serve static login page

app.listen(3000, function () { //start listening for activity on port 3000
  console.log('Listening on port 3000!');
});
```

This is for the database (where I'm setting the username in the session cookie)

```
Users.verifyUser = function(username, password, ws, req){
    Users.db.serialize(function(){
        Users.db.get('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?;', [username], function(err, row){
            var res = {redirect: false, url:  ''};
            if(row != null){
                verifyPass(username, password, row.hash, ws, res, req);
            }
            else{
                ws.send(JSON.stringify(res));
            }
        });
    });
};

function verifyPass (username, pass, hash, ws, res, req){
    // Verifying a hash 
    password(pass).verifyAgainst(hash, function(error, verified) {
        if (error)
            console.log("error");
        else if(verified) {
            req.session.cookie.username = username;
            res.redirect = true;
            res.url = game_url;
            // msg.url = 'localhost:3000/main.html';
        }
        ws.send(JSON.stringify(res));
    });
}
```

I've been reading about sessions with express but I'm really have trouble figuring it out. When the user is logged in the session cookie is fine on that page but once they're redirected to the game page or the page is refreshed the session is reset.

Comment: And `game_url` is of course on the same domain, with the same port, and the same protocol

Comment: Yeah, I just didn't want to put the actual url there.

Comment: Cookies can be persistent too. You can parse and check the cookie and then decide if you want to overwrite it—it doesn''t need to reset every page load. And instead of setting their username in a cookie, i would associate a unique cookie id with their username in the db and then save the id as the cookie so that its more obfuscated.

Comment: That's the problem, I want it to be persistent but the session Id changes every time it reloads. How to I make the cookies persistent?